# Android - Disable touch screen while animation

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm trying to implement a drop down like animation to my app, and disabling touch to its layout to prevent user tapping the view repeatedly.

I've tried using a transparent layout like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_mainLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_stepImageWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_stepImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/step1"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_orangEmailWrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/background2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_stepImageWrapper">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_orangEmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/orangemail"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_orangEmailWrapper">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/stepOneTitle"/>
<!--
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper_filler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clickable="false">
            </RelativeLayout>
-->
        </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTextWrapper"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/stepOneMessage"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_signup_step_one_touchDisabler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

The last layout with id `activity_signup_step_one_touchDisabler` is the transparent layout covering the whole wrapper layout.

I use it in my code like this :

```
RelativeLayout dropDown = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTitleWrapper);
        RelativeLayout dropDownMessage = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_dropdownTextWrapper);

        dropDownMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        dropDown.setOnClickListener(translateHandler);

        dropDownMessage.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            RelativeLayout touchDisabler = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_signup_step_one_touchDisabler);

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                touchDisabler.setClickable(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                touchDisabler.setClickable(false);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

So basically when `dropDown` is pressed, the `TextView` below it which is `dropDownMessage` is shown and hidden using sliding animation.

I tried setting `touchDisabler` which is the transparent layout to be clickable `onAnimationStart()` and to be unclickable `onAnimationEnd()`, but I can still tap it repeteadly, and the animation just stuck there while the whole textview blinks every tap.

What to do to disable the tap here?

Comment: Why dont you disable touch and click on the dropdown in the similar way

Comment: I want to show user the title like.. `"Press here to view terms and condition"` and the terms and condition will show itself when user press the view.. Is that what you were asking??

Comment: I am saying the onclick of the view which starts the animation, should be disabled before animation starts. Can you try that?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand it, how to disable the onClick of the layout? I am using layout to be clicked btw,  I was wrong when I said `View`.

Comment: dropDown.setClickable(false);

Comment: You can also play with boolean here. In your OnclickListener, use if and check whether the layout was clicked. If it wasn't then start the animation otherise do not.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work.. Where should I actually put it? inside onCreate right?